# How to troubleshoot duplicate entry duplicate entry: javax/annotation/ParametersAreNullableByDefault.class

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, gradle, crosswalk-runtime

I'm pretty new to the Gradle build system and Android Studio and cannot quite figure out how to resolve this issue.  My build is failing with:

```
  * What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':cyanEngine:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
  > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:      javax/annotation/ParametersAreNullableByDefault.class
```

If I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> and search for *ParametersAreNullableByDefault*.  One reference is pointing to **External Libraries** | **jsr305-1.3.9**.  The other is pointing to **classes.jar** under **xwalk_core_library**.

xwalk_core_library is referenced in my xwalk_cordova module via:

```
{
  android{
    dependencies{
        compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:11.40.277.7'
    }
}
```

And my app's gradle dependencies has:

```
compile project (':xwalk_cordova')
```

It seems like I need to get rid of the External Library, but I'm not sure where it's coming from.

Any pointers on how to resolve this?

**Update:**
I figured out the external reference was coming from Guava, referenced in the application build.gradle via `compile ('com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2')`.  Just updating to Guava version 18.0 seems to get me past this for now.  Guess the newer version no longer depends on jsr.

Still, I feel like I'll run into this again.  Basically, we had two 3rd party libraries depending on the same library.  What's the best way to clean this up?

I noticed for robolectic, there is an exclude, I'm guessing for similiar reasons:

```
testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2') {
    exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
}
```

I'm curious how this statement works and don't quite understand the Gradle docs.  What is this statement saying? Where do 'group' and 'module' come from?

Comment: Have you found the answer ?

Comment: @mjosh, haven't touched this in a long time, but I ended up using the solution mentioned in "Update".  If that doesn't work for you, I would suggest looking for the duplicate items and excluding one of them.